# Send mail from Outlook using QTP

Tags: outlook, qtp

I have a piece of code:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

myMail.To = "sandeep_raulo@infosys.com"
myMail.Subject = "Happy Birthday"
myMail.Body= "Happy Birthday"


myMail.Send
Wait(3)

Set myMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

I want to add some pictures in the mail body.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

myMail.To = "sandeep_raulo@infosys.com"
myMail.Subject = "Happy Birthday"
strBody = "<p>Happy Birthday</p>"
strBody = strBody & "<img src='Your Image Path' alt='Some name (optional)' width='Some Width' height='Some Height'>"
'For example: "<img src='Your Image Path' alt='XYZ' width='50' height='50'>"

myMail.HTMLBody = strBody

myMail.Send
Wait(3)

Set myMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

Here you are drafting email body as html body and embedding an image in it.